# Unable to Save Accounts: MISSING_ARGUMENT

Tags: apex, visualforce

my apex code:

```
public class ListExample {
 public list < account > myaccount {
  get;
  set;
 }
 public ListExample() {
  account a1 = new account(name = 'sam', type = 'prospect');
  account a2 = new account(name = 'ram', type = 'prospect');
  myaccount = new list < account > ();
  myaccount.add(a1);
  myaccount.add(a2);
 }
 public pagereference save() {
  update myaccount;
  return null;
 }
}
```

visualforce code:

```
<apex:page controller="ListExample">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!myaccount}" var="a">
<apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
<apex:column value="{!a.type}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
<apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!save}"/>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

when i clicked save it shows this error:
Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []
Error is in expression '{!save}' in component  in page listexamplevf: Class.ListExample.save: line 17, column 1
what is the problem can anyone help me

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use an **update**. Update only works if there is an ID already present in the database.

What you want is to use **insert** or **upsert** command.

Make sure , you are populating all the mandatory fields in Account record.

```
 public class ListExample {
 public list < account > myaccount {
  get;
  set;
 }
 public ListExample() {
  account a1 = new account(name = 'sam', type = 'prospect');
  account a2 = new account(name = 'ram', type = 'prospect');
  myaccount = new list < account > ();
  myaccount.add(a1);
  myaccount.add(a2);
 }
 public pagereference save() {
  upsert myaccount;
  return null;
 }
}
```

SRC: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_insert_update.htm

Answer (score 0):

This error is pretty straightforward: you can't perform an update on a record that doesn't exist yet. Since you created the Accounts in `myaccount`, you have to do a DML `insert`, before you can `update`. Since this looks like a toy example, you may be intending to do this in your constructor. It's not a typical sequence of operations for real code.

[Manipulate Records with DML](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_database/units/apex_database_dml) might be helpful in clarifying this kind of issue.